# If column 1 is a match, change value of column 3 using Awk

Tags: awk, sed, ksh

I have to edit a big file where the columns for each record are not delimited by a character but have a fixed lenght. I would like to search a value in the first column and if found, change the value of the 3rd column.

I can't take the file out from where it is so I can only use the command line with awk, sed and maybe java 5. otherwise I would try other solutions.

bigfile.dat structure:

```
Column1Col2Column3Column4Col5
```

Example:

```
id12345TEXTVALUE01SOMCODETEXT
id23456TEXTVALUE02SOMCODETEXT
id34567TEXTVALUE02SOMCODETEXT
id45678TEXTVALUE01SOMCODETEXT
id56789TEXTVALUE03SOMCODETEXT
```

What I need: set VALUE04 for id45678

```
id12345TEXTVALUE01SOMCODETEXT
id23456TEXTVALUE02SOMCODETEXT
id34567TEXTVALUE02SOMCODETEXT
id45678TEXTVALUE04SOMCODETEXT
id56789TEXTVALUE03SOMCODETEXT
```

I don't know if this is possible. Here is some pseudo code that I thought maybe could work with awk:

```
if (match id = subtr(Column1))
print subtr(Column1+Col2) + "mychange" +substr(Column4+Col5)
else
print unchanged line
```

I'm not asking to do my work for me I just don't know I'm wasting my time with the tools I have or I just lack the knowledge.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually quite easy to do with `awk`:

```
pax: awk <input.txt '/^id45678/{$0=substr($0,1,11)"VALUE04"substr($0,19)}1'
id12345TEXTVALUE01SOMCODETEXT
id23456TEXTVALUE02SOMCODETEXT
id34567TEXTVALUE02SOMCODETEXT
id45678TEXTVALUE04SOMCODETEXT
id56789TEXTVALUE03SOMCODETEXT
```

It just finds lines beginning with `id45678` and modifies that part of the line that you want changed.

The `1` at the end is simply a command to print the line whether changed or not (it's a "trick" using a truth value `1` to select the (default) action of printing the line).

Comment: This worked perfectly. It look so very simple but the truth is it would have taken me a very long time to get there. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk's `FIELDWIDTHS` for fixed width fields:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FIELDWIDTHS="7 4 7 7 4"  3  # set the field widths
    OFS=""                      
}
$1=="id45678" {                 # when the first field has the given value
    $3="VALUE04"                # replace the third field
}1' file                        # output
Column1Col2Column3Column4Col5
id12345TEXTVALUE01SOMCODETEXT
id23456TEXTVALUE02SOMCODETEXT
id34567TEXTVALUE02SOMCODETEXT
id45678TEXTVALUE04SOMCODETEXT
id56789TEXTVALUE03SOMCODETEXT
```

Comment: That's quite a nifty feature, one I wasn't aware of, and certainly worth an upvote.

Comment: This is cleaner, unfortunately we have an older awk version. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/^(id45678....)......./\1VALUE04/' file
```

or shorter:

```
sed -E 's/^(id45678.{4}).{7}/\1VALUE04/' file
```

and with variables:

```
s="id45678"
r="VALUE04"
sed -E 's/^('"$s"'.{4}).{7}/\1'"$r"'/' file
```

Output:

```
id12345TEXTVALUE01SOMCODETEXT
id23456TEXTVALUE02SOMCODETEXT
id34567TEXTVALUE02SOMCODETEXT
id45678TEXTVALUE04SOMCODETEXT
id56789TEXTVALUE03SOMCODETEXT
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

Comment: I don't know if there is any equivalent solution for the older sed, as this one does not support -E nor -i. Fortunately the awk solution worked. Thanks.

Comment: Without `-E` one of this could work: `sed 's/^\(id45678....\)......./\1VALUE04/'` `sed -r 's/^(id45678.{4}).{7}/\1VALUE04/' file`